# Mongoid replacement for MySQL's DateTime field tools like select * from posts where HOUR(posted) = 01

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I'm attempting to port a MySQL backed app to MongoDB with Mongoid. Some vital queries make use of MySQL's DateTime tools such as:

`select * from posts where HOUR(posted) = 01`

Where posted is a full DateTime timestamp. How can this be achieved using Mongoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB uses Javascript internally. You can send a piece of Javascript code as filter:

```
posts = Post.where("this.posted.getHours() == 1")
```